# Getting an "enum is not a class or namespace" error - C++

Tags: c++, enums

I declared an enum (called Direction) in a header file:

```
enum Direction {LEFT, RIGHT};
```

Then, i have a constructor that takes a Direction value and set it for another Direction variable (stringDirection).

```
bool InformationWidget::move(Direction direction){
    stringDirection=direction;

return true;
}
```

And finally, i have an if statement that checks the value of it:

```
if (stringDirection == Direction::RIGHT)
```

This is where i'm getting the error, at that if statement.. any ideas?
I tried looking around at previous threads but didn't find anything useful.

Thanks!

EDIT:

Here are my files:

Widget.h

```
enum class Direction {LEFT, RIGHT};

class Widget {
public:
     virtual bool...
     ...
};
```

information.h

```
class InformationWidget: public Widget {
public:
    ...
    Direction stringDirection;
    ...
};
```

information.cpp

```
void InformationWidget::show(){

...

if (stringDirection == LEFT) {
... }
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Declare your enum as `enum class` or `enum struct` if you want a scoped enum, i.e. to require the enumerators to be prefixed `Direction::`:

```
enum class Direction {LEFT, RIGHT};
```

Otherwise if you want an old C-style enum then you need to omit the namespace qualifier `Direction::` that the error message is complaining about:

```
if (stringDirection == RIGHT)
```

Notice that in the latter case the enumerator identifiers will be placed in the global namespace, which might cause them to clash with other identifiers.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I was aware of these solutions but both of them don't work.

When i try the first one (adding 'class') it still gives me the same error.
When i try the second one, it only gives an error for the RIGHT part of the if statement, saying "symbol 'RIGHT' could not be resolved".

Comment: Then you're doing something wrong somewhere else and need to provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I really don't know what's the problem here.. i declared the enum in header file, included it in a .cpp file (which implements methods from a purely abstract base class if it matters) and it's just not working..

Comment: Sorry, can't help without a reproducible example. (other than guess)

Comment: Judging by the snippets you added, you haven't included the header and you haven't specified the name of the scoped enum in front of the enumerator.

Comment: widget.h is included in both information.h and information.cpp, sorry for not including that.

and what do you mean? 'Direction' is name of the enumerator, like specified.

Comment: You did not write `Direction::LEFT` which is needed since you declared `Direction` as `enum class`.

Comment: Even when i do it still gives me the error of "Direction is not a class or namespace".

I don't know if it matters, but when i declare the enum it gives me a warning "scoped enums only available with -std=c++11...".

Regardless, even if i omit the word "class" from the enum declaration, and use "if (stringDirection==LEFT)" it doesn't work..

Comment: Yes, `enum class` is only available since C++11 so you should use `-std=c++11` to tell your compiler to compile as C++11. Or preferably C++14 while at it. Compile warnings are there _for a reason_. (Also that should've been a compile _error_, please check your compile options that they're sensible, e.g. `-pedantic-errors`.)

Comment: and how would i go about doing that? sorry i have no idea..

Comment: That depends on your build environment and thus is too broad to discuss here. I'm sure Google and/or Stack Overflow and/or your compiler/IDE docs will have the answer for that.

Comment: Yeah, found it! many thanks for your help!